# Displaying a NSCell with the number of children its row has

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I would like a NSCell in an OutlineView to display the number of the children the row it's has.
Here's what I mean:

[image]
<sub>(source: [sourceforge.net](http://allusions.sourceforge.net/articles/images/ordered.jpg))</sub>
 *What's on the right, but for all rows.*

How would I go about finding out, first, which row the NSCell is and then from there getting the number of children that row has.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PXSourceList](http://github.com/Perspx/PXSourceList) does this.

**edit** re: the comment about displaying the number of children in the badge

If you use the excellent PXSourceList, then you'll simply implement a single delegate method:

```
- (NSInteger)sourceList:(PXSourceList*)aSourceList badgeValueForItem:(id)item;
```

Most likely, you'll implement this as:

```
- (NSInteger)sourceList:(PXSourceList*)aSourceList badgeValueForItem:(id)item {
  return [self sourceList:aSourceList numberOfChildrenOfItem:item];
}
```

Comment: PXSourceList seems to only deal with the badge itself, not finding the number of children it's row has (bearing in mind I'm using Core Data).

Comment: @Joshua the cell shouldn't care about "children". That'd be coupling the View to your Model, which isn't recommended.  Instead, the View should simply have a number to draw there, but shouldn't care *where that number comes from*

Comment: Okay, I understand what you mean about keeping them separate. But how would I go about **displaying the number of children** the badges row has **inside the badge**?

Comment: Thanks, how much more complicated would it be if I didn't use PXSourceList and just used a Text Cell in the column as the badge?

Comment: @Joshua you'd have to create a custom NSCell subclass to do the drawing yourself.